# The Gods Themselves: role of the second part?

Tags: isaac-asimov, the-gods-themselves

I recently finished ["The Gods Themselves"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) by Isaac Asimov. While I enjoyed the whole book I was thinking about role of the second part in the book. It doesn't actually provide any details for the story seen from the our universe. All the assumptions and guesses that are made by humans were correct and second part just confirms them:

> The one who sent the message from para-Universe was opposed to the authorities. And that creatures from para-Universe are totally fine with Sun exploding.

The second part is such a self-contained story with little connections with other two. What role it plays then in book? I see only this: to show that "gods themselves" were actually not that much developed and were actually rather cynical and egoistical. And humanity regardless of all the stupidity that happened initially later beat the para-Universe humans and find a win-win solution?

Interesting idea from the comment [here](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book121.html): "No doubt Estwald telepathically communicates to Selene". That is nice but unconfirmed idea that would glue parts together.

Comment: [Jenkins' Guide seems to have an opinion opposite to you](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book121.html): he claims the second part is the best of the book, and the rest is fluff.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but: the second part is easily the best, in that it shows us "the other side", aliens who are not humans-in-disguise, and who have uncommon gender roles and lifecycle, and that's one goal of good SF. So the fact that it's enjoyable SF is a role in itself, given that we're speaking of a literary piece and not of a math proof :)

Comment: Asimov also wrote a metafictional short story based on that second part. I think it's called Gold.

Comment: @AndresF. if it is so cool by itself, why not it was released as a separate novel? Or why does it make less then half of book if other two parts are complimentary?

Comment: @Andrey Because book writing is not a mathematical process. Your question can be generalized to "in any given novel, why does the author decide to make one of the cool chapters just a chapter instead of a separate book?". It cannot be answered. It is a matter of taste. I know I enjoyed the first two chapters of The Gods Themselves more than the third; I could ask "why did Asimov write the third chapter, which I didn't like?", but doing so would be pointless.

Comment: @AndresF. third part concludes the story, so it is well placed. May be not the best, but right where it should have been. I tend to disagree with you, rarely you can just remove a part of the book without messing up the plot. Actually book writing process is usually well planned thing and it not done randomly.

Comment: @Andrey If you read what I wrote, you are actually _agreeing_ with me: rarely you can just remove a part of the book without messing it up, which is why Asimov didn't. As for _why_, I didn't say books are unplanned (though many books are); I just said that decisions are stylistic rather than mathematical. Parts are not culled if they are interesting, and the second chapter in The Gods Themselves is definitely unique, interesting and (I'm willing to bet) what most readers remember about the book.

Comment: The 2nd part was published in a different magazine than the first 2, If vs Galaxy (although both were put out by the same publishing company).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe I'm being a little unfair, but I've never regarded Asimov as an author who went in for deep philosophical insights. Many (most?) of his books are thinly disguised whodunnits. Before I get too many downvotes I should emphasise that I, like many of us, started out reading Asimov's short stories and I love almost all of what Asimov has written. Arguably his popular science books were a factor in me deciding to become a scientist.

Anyhow, I don't think you should look for anything deep in the second part, but rather consider what the book would be like without it. We'd have the problem then the solution without ever understanding how the problem arose. The second part is important to the book because it explains that the "God's" were people just like us trying to survive. As I recall Asimov doesn't go into any deep arguments by the aliens about how justified their actions are, but I note plenty of example from human history of humans placing their welfare above others.

For the record, as a fourteen year old nerd I **loved** the book :-)

Comment: Well, you just gave the same arguments that I gave about it's role.

Comment: You say the "Gods" are "cynical and egoistical" but this isn't the way I remember it. As I recall Dua is opposed to the plan, and even at the end of the second part Estwald seems more sorrowful and resigned than cynical and egotistical. I've just finished my current book (Salem's Lot!) so maybe I'll dig out my copy of the book and reread it.

Comment: Dua was sort of dissident, and official position was rather cynical. They openly stated that they are fine with Sun explosion, and did nothing to warn Earth people. Why? Because they were afraid that humans will just shut the pump down. Also Estwald's thoughts are not represented at all so I am not sure how did you drew conclusion.

Comment: Hmm, I need to go away and reread the book before commenting further.

Comment: OK, the last line of part 2 is: Estwald stepped forth and said sadly to the waiting Hard Ones, by way of vibrating air waves, "I am permanently with you now, and there is much to do—"
It doesn't sound as if he (it?) was pleased he could now continue his plans.

Comment: I think it sounds pretty neutral.

Answer (score 7):

The idea for middle section of "The Gods Themselves" came first.  Asimov had several reasons for writing it.  There had been complaints that he did not write about aliens or 'sex scenes'.  He then had a conversation with Robert Silverberg about the fictional element plutonium-186. So Asimov thought up a parallel universe with different fundimental laws, and an alien species with three 'genders'. With this central part of the story in mind, he then turned to the 'before' and 'after' taking place in our universe/world.

Comment: Ok, but still this doesn't answer a question: what role it play? Why couldn't he just release that as a separate novel? Also yeah, I read wikipedia.

Comment: Much like b_jonas and Andres mention, the second part is the genesis of the whole story. It is the part Asimov wanted to tell. But an Asimov story about aliens? Better to have some sort of lead in, with humans,  so when the POV shifts, we're already interested in the story.  Part three is just some closure for the humans, as the aliens are willing to let our universe explode.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the story is set in the parallel universe. It shows how Bronowski received the message from the parallel universe and the reason why the para-men won't turn off the electron pump.
I guess it shows that the people/beings in the parallel universe are not as intelligent as Lamont believed them to be and provides a connection from 'Against Stupidity' and 'Contend In Vain'.

Asimov's short story 'Gold' is about a man who is trying to create 'compu-drama' of the second section and reading this provides more information about the Parentals, Emotionals and Rationals and I found it useful to read after I finished 'The Gods Themselves'.